# Force specific application to use VPN/Proxy?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, proxy

I play Blizzard games. But couple days in a row Blizzard application says "You've made too many attempts." and I can't login on my PC. Same if I rty to login on web page, but with browser VPN web page allow login. Also can't login on my mobile phone via WiFi. But if I use 4G internet on phone - I can login and play. I guess they blocked my WAN IP on router.

So my question is - is there way to install some VPN/Proxy and force Blizzard app to use it like browser VPN? But leave all other applications untouched.

Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I use Private Internet Access VPN and it tunnels *all my applications and traffic* through the VPN, so what you're asking shouldn't be a problem, with any VPN provider I would think.

You can specify which apps you don't want going through the VPN, but that's the opposite of what you're looking for!

Comment: Should add..I have nothing to do with Private Internet Access VPN besides a long-time user. That's it. Not promoting or advertising anything!

Comment: "all my applications" Op was asking for "specific application".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force an app to use your VPN connection by copying and editing your (Windows) VPN connection.

1. Open the run prompt with: `WIN+R`
2. Type: **`ncpa.cpl`**
3. Copy your "old VPN" to `APP_VPN` (for example)
4. Open a *Normal* user Powershell
5. Change the new VPN connection with:

```
Add-VpnConnectionTriggerApplication -Name "APP_VPN" –ApplicationID "C:\path-to-your\game.exe" -Force

# Enable (Application) split-tunneling
Set-VpnConnection -Name "APP_VPN" -SplitTunneling $True
```

You can also check the VPN settings details in the *phonebook* in:
`C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`

Done!

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill Hi yes, I agree, sorry about that. But now I can't find my other post. Did you already delete it?